# JBOSS Application SSL Error: Alias name does not identify a key entry

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, jboss6.x, keytool

I am trying to configure JBOSS application 6.0.1 using SSL with a certificate provided to me(By entrust).

I got three certificate(root,chain & server certificate) from Entrust in .CER format.

Next I created a keystore:

1.keytool -import -alias EntrustL1C -keystore EntrustL1C.mykeystore -trustcacerts -file L1Cchain.cer
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
Certificate was added to keystore

2.keytool -import -alias Root -keystore EntrustL1C.mykeystore -trustcacerts -file L1Croot.cer
Enter keystore password:

3.# keytool -import -alias myalias -keystore EntrustL1C.mykeystore -trustcacerts -file entrustcert.cer
Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore

I configured this in JBOSS's standalone.xml in the two SSL section:

Upon starting JBOSS application I got this error.

```
13:08:23,311 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Error initializing endpoint: java.io.IOException: Alias name test does not 
identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:517) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:452) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:168) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:978) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:1001) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:268) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]

13:08:23,320 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.https: 

org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.https: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:272)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Alias name test does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:1003)
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:268)
    ... 5 more
```

I then did a keytool -list -v -keystore EntrustL1C.mykeystore, and noticed that the alias is in all are there in lowercase.

I am wondering if I am making some fundamental error in configuring JBOOS application, or should this thing be working and I'm just making a stupid careless mistake?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your JBoss configuration you are referring to an alias with the name "test". Since your keystore does not have such alias, JBoss complains. Doing a global search for "test" (try also with included quotes) across your JBoss configuration files (XML, properties, etc. ...) may help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the standalone.xml make sure you make entry under as below

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
            <ssl name="Certificate issued to Name" key-alias="mykey" password="123456" certificate-key-file="Localtion of Keystore file" cipher-suite="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" protocol="TLSv1.2" verify-client="false"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens XML code below was invisible because of wrong formatting

Comment: The above was just a sample. Don't use directly. You need to modify your XML as per your need